# Find $\mathbb{P}[\exists n>0 : X_n=j \mid X_0=i]$ in Markov Process

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $\left\{B_n\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be an i.i.d. process, such that, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup{0}$:

$$\mathbb{P}[B_n=-1]=p \\ \mathbb{P}[B_n=+1]=q$$

Such that $p+q=1$. Let $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n=0}^\infty\subset\mathbb{S}$ be a **markov chain**, where $\mathbb{S}=\left\{i\right\}_{i=0}^K=\left\{0,1,...,K\right\}$ for some $K\in\mathbb{N}$, such that:

$$X_n=X_{n-1}+B_{n}\qquad0<X_{n-1}<K \\ X_n=X_{n-1}\qquad\qquad \ \ X_{n-1}\in\left\{0,K\right\}$$

I drew the diagram of the process in order to see things more clearly:
[image]

Define the probabilty $\rho_{ij}$ for every $i,j\in\mathbb{S}\setminus\left\{0,K\right\}$ such that:

$$\rho_{ij}\triangleq\mathbb{P}[\exists n>0 : X_n=j \mid X_0=i]$$

(In other words, $\rho_{ij}$ is the probability that the chain would somewhen visit the state {$j$}, given that the initial state is {$i$}. It is clear that if the initial state is $X_0=0$, then it is certain that the chain would visit the state {$0$} again, but never any other state. In other words, $\rho_{0k}=\delta[k]$ where $\delta$ is the delta of kronecker.)

It is given that $p=q=1/2$. Find $\rho_{ij}$ for every $i,j\in\mathbb{S}\setminus\left\{0,K\right\}$.

---

I feel like I've tried everything. It seems that doing this straightforward is impossible, since the total number of paths that must be considered is too large. I understand that the expression would be different for the three cases $i=j,i>j$ and $i<j$. Finding $\rho_{ii}$ shouldn't be a problem if I knew $\rho_{ij}$ for $i>j$ and $i<j$, since:

$$\rho_{ii}=p\rho_{i-1,i}+q\rho_{i+1,i}=[\rho_{i-1,i}+\rho_{i+1,i}]/2$$

And obviously $i>i-1$ & $i<i+1$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm a bit lost in notation, what is $X_0$?

Comment: @copper.hat $X_0$ is the initial state of the chain. For example, if $X_0=4$, then $X_1=3$ with probability $p=1/2$ or $X_1=5$ with probability $q=1/2$. I am required to compute $\rho_{ij}$, meaning the initial state is $X_0=i$, and I need to find what is the probability that the chain would somewhen visit the state $j$.

For example, $\rho_{00}=1$ and $\rho_{05}=0$, because if you start from the state {$0$}, it is certain that the chain will visit the state {$0$} again, and it is certain that it will never reach the state {$5$} (since the state {$0$} is a closed connected group).

Comment: Is it an integer, positive, ...?

Comment: @copper.hat $X_0\in\mathbb{S}=\left\{0,1,2,...,K\right\}$ where $K\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Sorry, I see you did define it. Excuse my inattention :-(.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:
Merge states $1$ and $2$, and also $K-1$ and $K$. Find the transition matrix $P_{(K-2)\times (K-2)}$ for the new $(K-2)$-state Markov chain, which the elements of $P^n$ gives you the transition probabilities for states $3$ to $K-2$. A conditional probability would yield the desired result for the inner states of the two merged states.